# Integrating Hbase that Holds Nutch Crawled Data and Solr

Tags: solr, amazon-web-services, hbase, nutch

I have a Hbase Database that holds crawled information of wikipedia.org. My machine is at Amazon Wweb Services.

I have downloaded the Solr and I want to index the data at Hbase after that I will make search on it.

I am new to Solr and Hbase, how can I do that?

Comment: If you are using Nutch to crawl data in to hbase, then you can use Solr with Nutch to index. Please check here http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/CommandLineOptions

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is, run this command - `sudo bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/ -reindex`

But before you do that please make sure your solr instance is up and running which you can verify by visiting this link `http://localhost:8983/solr/` and if you can find Solr admin then your Solr instance is running.

Comment: What is the difference between -reindex and -index ?

Comment: as the words suggests -reindex would be to reindex any exiting indexed content and also to index any new content.

Comment: How to reindex data for more than 1 tables in hbase where crawled data is residing.